# Encryption in PHP leaves unwanted characters

Tags: php, encryption

I have made an encryption function which encrypts a simple value and stores it in the database. Here is the code to encrypt and decrypt:

```
public function encrypt($string){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $value = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key256, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $value = base64_encode($value);
    return $value;
}

public function decrypt($string){
    $value = base64_decode($string);
    $value = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key256, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return $value;
}
```

When I encrypt a simple value such as 'Michael' and decrypt again, I get the value:

```
Michael���������
```

Is there a reason I get all those question marks or a way to get rid of them?

Comment: Have you tried outputting every step?
Where are the � appearing first? Only after decrypting with mcrypt or already before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience, those extra character are NULL-bytes used for padding, that has been preserved after decryption.

You should try changing your `decrypt()` function to:

```
public function decrypt($string){
    $value = base64_decode($string);
    $value = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key256, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return trim($value, "\0");
}
```

Comment: The problem with stripping null bytes is...  what if you're encrypting binary data that happens to have null bytes in it?  For that reason, I prefer PKCS#7 padding.  ie. You add x bytes to the end, each with a value of x, such that strlen($plaintext) + x is a multiple of the block size.  If $plaintext is already a multiple of the block size you add block size bytes each with a value of block size (ie. you always remove bytes; the only question is how many)

Answer (score -1):

use `bin2hex()` instead of `bas64_encode()` and you can use the `hex2bin()` before decryption instead of `base64_decode()`

```
protected function hex2bin($hexdata) 
{
 $bindata = '';
 for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
 $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
     }

  return $bindata;
}
```

Ofcourse you can use `hex2bin()` in PHP., this custom code  is for compatibility with `Java` like platforms.
I do it this way. May be you can give a try.

Thanks